# Union for Nested Spark Data Frames

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose we have two data frames `df1` and `df2` with the following schema:

```
A
 |-- B: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b3: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- C: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- D: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- d1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- d2: string (nullable = true)
```

Would `df1.union(df2)`work for these nested data frames if you wanted to add a new record? Or would you have to flatten them first if you wanted to add a new record?

Comment: does your df2 contain the new records that you want to add to df1, hence you want to do the union?

Comment: @VikasSaxena: Yes

Comment: it will work in that case.

Comment: @VikasSaxena: But the union has more rows than each individual data frame. So you probably have to flatten it.

Comment: will you be able to post an example of the input dataframes and the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, here is a knowledge article by databricks
https://kb.databricks.com/data/append-a-row-to-rdd-or-dataframe.html

and you won't need to flatten your struct fields.

PS: Please ensure your column are in same orders in both dataframe.